# Variable Running Total in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a function in python where the user inputs a column of meaning full values and a number, call it X. The function will then create a running total over X of those meaning full values over.

For example, for a series A, and X = 3:

```
import random 
mylist = []
for i in range(0,100):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    mylist.append(x)
a = pd.Series(mylist)
a.head()
Out:
 0    2
 1    5
 2    2
 3    8
 4    8
 5    6
```

so my_func() would return this new sereis (as the third column):

```
 0    2   Nan
 1    5   Nan
 2    2   9 # 2+5+2
 3    8   15 # 5+2+8
 4    8   18 # 2+8+8
 5    6   22 # 8+8+6
```

I thought of using `cumsum()` in some way, but had trouble wrapping my head around the X part of it. And truthfully I did not know where to start.

Comment: It looks like what you want is a rolling sum of the last 3 values. Try ```a.rolling(3).sum()```

Comment: You should have wrote this as an answer. You are correct and were the first person, thus you should get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rolling sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and specify the window(in your case 3). 
Some like this would work:

```
In [348]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[348]: 
0  2
1  5
2  2
3  8
4  8
5  6

In [350]: df.rolling(window=3).sum()                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[350]: 
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     9.0
3    15.0
4    18.0
5    22.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df
```

[image]

[Rolling sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html)

```
df['runningsum']=df.rolling(3).s.sum()
df
```

Output

[image]

Comment: There is a minor spelling mistake. However, it is not long enough to edit. 'Rolling' object has no attribute 's'. There should not be an `s` between `).s.sum()`. Should change to `).sum()`

Comment: Thanks. What version are you on? It can be df['runningsum']=df.s.rolling(3).sum()
 or df['runningsum']=df.rolling(3).s.sum(). All work in 0.25.0, maybe I should test that on version 1.0.1 on my other pc?

Comment: I am using pandas 0.24.2 from anacondas. Hence that is why. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking into a more optimised Pandas or Numpy solution, but for the sake of completeness, I am suggesting here a pure-python version of the function. It implements a generator, so that in many cases it may be a quite simple, yet performant, option, without any external dependencies:

```py
def my_func2(data, x):
    i = 1
    for n in data:
        if i < x:
            yield 0  # ignore the first numbers
        else:       
            yield sum(data[i-x:i]) # sum the current number and previous x-1 numbers.
        i += 1



mylist = [2, 5, 2, 8, 8, 6]

# The enumerate() part is just a way to generate the counting on the left
for i, n in enumerate(my_func2(mylist, 3)):
    print(f"{i:5}: {n:9}")
```